# Как правильно повернуть часть объекта, чтобы она следила за другим объектом?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создал объект состоящий из множества частей, как правильно повернуть одну из частей объекта, чтобы она следила за другим объектом, используя LookAt если возможно? 
Когда я использую LookAt, то часть первого объекта поворачивается боком, а не передом.

А также как повернуть объект, чтобы он следил за другим объектом по одной оси?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для поворота по одной оси, нужно после lookat искусственно обнулять оси которые не должны меняться.
Если поворачивается боковой стороной, можно изменить модель, или искусственно после lookat повернуть по одной из осей.
Если вы поворачиваете кость, и модель выглядит не корректно, нужно настроить непосредственно скелет.